# In SharePoint 2013, the uploaded videos are not playing on ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, ipad, sharepoint, video, media

I have uploaded .mp4 videos to an Assest Library in SharePoint 2013. I can play these videos on IE and other browers but I am unable to play them on IPhone and IPAD. It is asking for Silverlight Installation. Is there any way I can play my videos on them.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the native sharepoint is not possible. You can create a player with html5 to be able to play these videos.

Comment: @Tiago: I created an html5 player and tried to play the video but when I open my sharepoint site in pc view on iphone or on ipad, there is a cross sign which appears on the player and the video does not play. Is there any option available with IOS which can help. Please suggest.

Comment: This link can help you: http://gavinb.net/2011/07/19/serving-html5-video-from-sharepoint-document-libraries/ remembering that this only works in full sharepoint, the foundation version does not work

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation. You need to make an additional extra change. Initially I couldn't believe, but it is necessary to enable the blobcache for that SharePoint web application that is hosting the mp4 files in order to make them available for iPad / iPhone. When you enable the blobcache please make sure you have mp4 added as extension.
Here is an example of how the blobcache entry should look like in your web.config file. Of course please add the required adjustments based on your environment: cache location, size, extensions...

```
<BlobCache location="D:\SPS\BlobCache" path="\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|jfif|bmp|dib|tif|tiff|themedbmp|themedcss|themedgif|themedjpg|themedpng|ico|png|wdp|hdp|css|js|asf|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|rm|rmvb|wma|wmv|ogg|ogv|oga|webm|xap)$" maxSize="10" enabled="true" />
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and tried enabling blobcache.  I see the mp4 file getting cached on the server, but I still have the same issue when trying to access from IOS.  Now I'm wondering if I need to install the Application Request Routing extension to IIS as I think this enables byte range requests and/or IIS smooth streaming.  Thoughts?  Here is a link that indicates that byte range requests are needed: http://blog.sallarp.com/why-your-video-refuse-to-play-on-ipad-iphone/

Comment: Well, I am reading that blob cache enables byte-range requests here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee424404(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I figured it out.  It was the Blob Cache, but you have to enable it for all WFEs even if you have affinity to a single WFE.  I wrote a post about it here: http://www.threewill.com/sharepoint-videos-ios-safari-iphone-ipad-unforgiving/

Comment: I can't believe this has been here since Nov 2014 and nobody ever edited it to make the XML example show up...

Comment: followed all the changes, working as expected in html5 with video tag, but occasionally encounter issues popped up with windows login dialog asking to input password, anyone encounter similar issues? ( and we are running multiple WFE)

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to get Silverlight on an Iphone/Ipad.
You should be able to simply download the mp4 files and play them direct from your device.

Comment: The video output by default is HTML5 with silverlight fallback. 

Also, when implementing our own video player and using a video file (.mp4) from a document library - we are currently experiencing an issue where it will not load on ipads. The same video, with the same video player loads correctly on our LAMP server, I'm suspecting issues with MIME types or cache at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I had a video rendition set in the asset library and this caused a different video menu, and prompted to install Silverlight. Set the video properties so it forces the main video as default and it should play on iPad.
Cheers.